# Is it possible to add a float to a double?

Tags: java

Our teacher asked us to search about this and what I kept on getting from the net are explanations stating what double and float means.

Can you tell me whether it is possible or not, and explain why or why not?

Comment: Why don't you try it, you'll soon see if it's possible.

Comment: Even though I wanted to, we still don't know how to construct such programs yet. This is just an introductory question from our prof. But anyway, thank you! :) I'll try it as soon as I've learned constructing one. God bless!

Comment: Allright! Btw: `class Main { public static void main(String[] args) { double x=1; float y = 2; x += y; System.out.println( x ); } }`.

Comment: Your prof is asking you intricate questions about floating point calculations, yet you've never written a computer program? That is crazy. Don't wait for your prof, just start programming yourself.

Answer (score 5):

Simple answer: yes, but only if the `double` is not too large.

`float`'s are *single-precision* floating point numbers, meaning they use a 23-bit mantissa and 8-bit exponent, corresponding to ~6/7 s.f. precision and ~ 10^38 range.

`double`'s are *double-precision* - with 52-bit mantissa and 11-bit exponent, corresponding to ~14/15 s.f. precision and ~ 10^308 range.

Since double's have larger range than floats, adding a float to a *very* large double will nullify the float's effects (called underflow). Of course this can happen for two double types as well.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point

Comment: I don't think that is called underflow (at least I've never heard it called that). Underflow is when you do something like `Integer.MIN_VALUE - 1` and get a positive answer.

Comment: @PaulBoddington underflow is when an operation truncates the value of an operand because its relative value is too small. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_underflow

Answer (score 2):

Can you add two numbers with varying decimal places (e.g. `432.54385789364 + 432.1`)? Yes you can.

In Java, it is the same idea.

From the [Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html):

> - float: The float data type is a single-precision 32-bit IEEE 754 floating point. Its range of values is beyond the scope of this discussion, but is specified in the Floating-Point Types, Formats, and Values section of the Java Language Specification. As with the recommendations for byte and short, use a float (instead of double) if you need to save memory in large arrays of floating point numbers. This data type should never be used for precise values, such as currency. For that, you will need to use the java.math.BigDecimal class instead. Numbers and Strings covers BigDecimal and other useful classes provided by the Java platform.
> - double: The double data type is a double-precision 64-bit IEEE 754 floating point. Its range of values is beyond the scope of this discussion, but is specified in the Floating-Point Types, Formats, and Values section of the Java Language Specification. For decimal values, this data type is generally the default choice. As mentioned above, this data type should never be used for precise values, such as currency.

Basically, they are both holders to decimals. The way that they are different is how precise they can be. A `float` can only be `32` bits in size, compared to a `double` which is `64` bits in size. A `float` can have precision up to around 5 or 6 float point numbers, and a `double` can have precision up to around 10 floating point numbers.

Basically... a `double` can store a decimal better than a `float`... but takes up more space.

---

To answer your question, you can add a `float` to a `double` and vice versa. Generally, the result will be made into a `double`, and you will have to cast it back to a `float` if that is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be really deep about it you should say yes it is possible due to value coercion, but that it opens the door for more severe precision errors to accumulate invisibly to the compiler.  **float** has substantially precision than **double** and is very regrettably the default type of literal floating-point numbers in Java source.  In practice make sure to use the **d** suffix on literals to make sure theh are **double** if you have to use floating point.

These precision errors can lead to serious harm and even loss of life in sensitive systems.

Floating point is very hard to use correctly and should be avoided if possible.  One extremely obvious thing not to do that is commonly mistakenly done is representing currency as a **float** or **double**.  This can cause real money to be effectively given to or stolen from people.

Floating point (preferring **double**) is appropriate for approximate calculations and certain high performance scientific computing applications.  However it is still extremely important to be aware of the precision loss characteristics particularly when a resulting floating point value is fed into further floating-point calculations.

This more generally leads in Numerical Computing and now I've really gone afield :)

SAS has a decent paper on this:
http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings11/275-2011.pdf